# Comparison of floating point numbers in Java

Tags: java

Lets say, I have the following:

```
float x= ...
float y = ...
```

What I like to do is just compare them whether x is greater than y or not. I am not interested in their equality.

My question is, should I take into account precision when just performing a > or a < check on floating point values? Am I correct to assume that precision is only taken into account for equality checks?

Comment: yes, you are correct. < and > are safe

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much. Lets say I have an array of 3 floats that have been computed from my code. I like to find out which are equal to each other. How do I then go about setting my precision? I know that these numbers are between 0 and 1 and are set to 4 decimal places.

Comment: @MGorgon - incorrect.  Or at least, not always correct.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have two floats, named x and y, and if there hasn't been any casting before, you can easily use ">" and "<" for comparison. However, let's say if you had two doubles d1 and d2 with d1 > d2 and you cast them to f1 and f2, respectively, you might get f1 == f2 because of precision problems.

Comment: I should add that hard coded numbers might also act differently:
    `float f1 = 0.123456788f;
    float f2 = 0.123456789f;
    System.out.println(f2 > f1); // false`
... because the compiler won't check the precision.

Comment: This does not take account of errors ... which is the real reason why using '==' to compare floating point values is wrong.

Comment: I read your answer, Stephen, and I see your point. That's why I said "Since you already HAVE two floats". That was meant assuming that you KNOW that the two floats that you have ARE correct. Then "<" and ">" will work just fine.
But yes, in the end it all depends on where these numbers come from and in most cases (e.g. if they are returned by methods) it's impossible to verify their correctness.

Comment: I am not sure why I get 0 in all the three cases:float a = 0.15f + 0.15f;
  float b = 0.1f + 0.2f;
  float c=.3f;
  System.out.println(Float.compare(a,  b));
  System.out.println(Float.compare(a,  c));
  System.out.println(Float.compare(b,  c));

Comment: Because they ARE all equal, they all result in 0.3 as value. Look it up in the JavaDocs for Float.compare(f1, f2) 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compare(float,%20float)
It says that the method will return 0 if they are "numerical equal".

Answer (score 1):

There is already a wheel you don't need to invent:

```
if (Float.compare(x, y) < 0)
    // x is less than y
```

All `float` values have the same precision as each other.

Comment: This does not take account of errors ... which is the real reason why using '==' to compare floating point values is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on where those two floats came from. If there was roundoff earlier in their computation, then if the accumulated roundoff is large enough to exceed the difference between the "ideal" answers, you may not get the results you expect for any of the comparison values.

As a general rule, any comparison of floats must be considered fuzzy. If you must do it, you are responsible for understanding the sources of roundoff error and deciding whether you care about it and how you want to handle it if so. It's usually better to avoid comparing floats entirely unless your algorithm absolutely requires that you do so... and if you must, to make sure that a "close but not quite" comparison will not break your program. You may be able to restructure the formulas and order of computation to reduce loss of precision. Going up to double will reduce the accumulated error but is not a complete solution.

If you must compare, and the comparison is important, don't use floats.  If you need absolute precision of floating-like numbers, use an infinite-precision math package like bignums or a rational-numbers implementation and accept the performance cost. Or switch to scaled integers -- which also round off, but round off in a way that makes more sense to humans.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult question.  The answer really depends on how you got those numbers.

---

First, you need to understand that floating point numbers ARE precise, but that they don't necessarily represent the number that you thought they did.  Floating point types in typical programming language represent a *finite* subset of the *infinite* set of Real numbers.  So if you have an arbitrary real number the chances are that you cannot represent it precisely using a `float` or `double` type.  In fact ...

> The only Real numbers that can be represented *exactly* as `float` or
>   `double` values have the form
>
> ```
>   mantissa * power(2, exponent)
> ```
>
> where "mantissa" and "exponent" are integers in prescribed ranges.

And the corollary is that most "decimal" numbers don't have an exact `float` or `double` representation either.

So in fact, we end up with something like this:

```
 true_value = floating_point_value + delta,
```

where "delta" is the error; i.e. the small (or not so small) difference between the true value and the `float` or `double` value.

---

Next, when you perform a calculation using floating point values, there are cases where the exact result cannot be represented as a floating point value.  An obvious example is:

```
1.0f / 3.0f
```

for which the true value is 0.33333... recurring, which is not representable in any finite base 2 (or base 10!) floating point representation.  Instead what happens is that a result is produced by *rounding* to the nearest `float` or `double` value ... introducing more error.

As you perform more and more calculations, the errors can *potentially* grow ... or stay stable ... depending on the sequence of operations that are performed.  (There's a branch of mathematics that deals with this: Numerical Analysis.)

---

So back to your questions:

> *"Should I take into account precision when just performing a > or a < check on floating point values?"*

It depends on how you got those floating point values, and what you know about the "delta" values relative to the true Real values they nominally represent.

- If there are no errors (i.e. delta < the smallest representable difference for the value), then you can safely compare using `==`, `<` or `>`.
- If there are possible errors, then you need to take account of those errors ... if the semantic of the comparison are intended to couched in terms of the (nominal) true values.  Furthermore, you need to have a credible estimate of the "delta" (the accumulated error) when you code the comparison.

In short, there is no simple (correct) answer ...

> *"Am I correct to assume that precision is only taken into account for equality checks? "*

In fact precision is not "taken into account" in *any* of the comparison operators.  These operators treat the operands as **precise** values, and compare them accordingly.  It is up to your code to take account of precision issues, based on your error estimates for the preceding calculations.

---

If you have estimates for the deltas, then a mathematically sound `<` comparison would be something like this:

```
// Assume true_v1 = v1 +- delta_v1 ... (delta_v1 is a non-negative constant)

if (v1 + delta_v1 < v2 - delta_v2) {
    // true_v1 is less than true_v2
}
```

and so on ...

Comment: Thank you Stephen, I learnt a lot from your detailed explanation. I have an array of 3 float values. The values are computed by some equations that I have in my code. The values in the array are not hard coded. Now I like to perform a check which of these 3 values are equal to each other. Can you please explain how will I approach this? Also something like Float.compare(float x1, float x2) is recommended for this approach?

Comment: `Float.compare` does not take account of error deltas.  If you want to take account of the errors properly, then you need an estimate of the *maximum* error.

Comment: Ok. As I have these float values computed via some equations based on some user input, I do not know the true value. But, because these floating values are computed via some equations, and when I compare them against each other computed values using == or < or >, there should be no issues? As I understand the precision is important when I have a true value that needs to be compared against.

Comment: *"But, because these floating values are computed via some equations, and when I compare them against each other computed values using == or < or >, there should be no issues?"*  - Incorrect.  There could be issues.  The point is that any computation using floating point is *potentially* going to involve errors and that is *potentially* going to cause comparisons to give unexpected answers.  (Especially, when the "expectations" are from naive end-users who don't understand the limitations of computer computation.)